# Xcode8 beta 6 - URLSession with completionHandler argument not working

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest, xcode8-beta6

I can't seem to use this method in my code at all after changing from beta 5 til beta 6.

```
    open func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) -> URLSessionDataTask
```

My code:

```
        let task = self.createSession().dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            self.handleTaskResult(data: data, response: response, error: error, completionHandler: completionHandlerIncoming)
        })
```

I get that `"Cannot invoke 'dataTask' with an argument list of type '(with: URLRequest, completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)'"`. Even though this is the completion of the function xcode gives me.

If I then try:

```
        let task = self.createSession().dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            self.handleTaskResult(data: data, response: response, error: error, completionHandler: completionHandlerIncoming)
        }
```

It still does not work.

**UPDATE:**

I found out that I was calling handleTaskResult which had error as `NSError?`, but error is now `Error?`, after changing this, it compiles!

Comment: I cannot spot an error at first sight. Does it compile with an "empty" completion handler `{ (data, response, error) in }` ?

Comment: yes it does compile when empty, so I'm wondering if its anything inside, I will experiment some more.

Comment: Oh I found out what it was! I had a parameter with NSError but now the completionHandler uses Error, how ever I got the error on the other line.... hmmmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I was calling handleTaskResult which had error as `NSError?`, but error is now `Error?`, after changing this, it compiles!